# Gradient of Schwarzschild horizon

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, event-horizon, vector-fields

I am studying Schwarzschild horizon and badly stuck with some Math stuff

Consider the scalar field defined on Manifold by
$$
u(t,r,\theta,\phi)=(1-\frac{r}{2m})e^{\frac{r-t}{4m}}
$$

$$
du=\frac{1}{4m} e^{\frac{r-t}{4m}} [-(1-\frac{r}{2m})dt -( 1+\frac{r}{2m})dr]
$$

The corresponding gradient vector field is computed from $\nabla^{\alpha}u=g^{\alpha \mu} \nabla_{\mu}u$

where g is ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein metric

What I don't understand is the following equation :

$$\nabla u = \frac{1}{4m} e^{\frac{r-t}{4m}}[-(1+\frac{r}{2m})\partial_{t}+(1-\frac{r}{2m})\partial_{r}]$$

Can someone help me how to get the last equation i.e. the gradient vector field.
I am trying to use the ordinary definition of $\nabla$ vector
$$
\nabla =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z} k$$
but seems it doesn't work here.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a thing that is defined for Cartesian coördinates for something that is clearly meant to be spherically symmetric and already expressed in polar coördinates? Not to mention that you are using space-alone entities on a thing that is much more sensibly seen on spacetime as a whole?